# Difference in size between text and math in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontsize, size

I am using some of the settings found in this Beamer Tutorial: https://github.com/paulgp/beamer-tips/blob/master/slides.tex
to create my presentations. As a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}      % o1r try Darmstadt, arsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Utiliser \LaTeX{}}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item \lipsum[1][1]
     \item On peut démontrer que $1+2+3\ldots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
     \item 
Pour série géométrique \(1+3+9+27+81+\ldots\) le premier terme est $a=1$. Chaque terme de la suite peut être écrit à partir du terme précédent en le multipliant par le facteur $r=3$. Ce facteur est la raison (ratio commune) de la suite. Le terme général de cette suite est alors: \[u_k=f(k)=3^{k-1}, \quad k\in \mathbb{N}^*\]
 \item Pour calculer la somme 
\[
1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots+n^3=\sum_{r=1}^n r^3
\]
on utilise la formule
\(
(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1
\). On arrive alors au résultat 
\[
\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2
\]
 \end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

May be my impression is wrong but I believe there is a difference in font size between normal text and math text. Am I missing something? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different fonts for math and for text. Unless two fonts where specifically designed to be used together, chances are pretty high that they will have a slightly different height.

The `lato` package comes with a `scale` option which you can use to scale it to match the size of your math font.  If you scale them to be exactly the same height, the result will look odd because of the different heaviness of the fonts. I think something like 0.95 might be a good compromise:

```
\documentclass[11pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{lato}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}      % o1r try Darmstadt, arsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Utiliser \LaTeX{}}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item \lipsum[1][1]
     \item On peut démontrer que $1+2+3\ldots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
     \item 
Pour série géométrique \(1+3+9+27+81+\ldots\) le premier terme est $a=1$. Chaque terme de la suite peut être écrit à partir du terme précédent en le multipliant par le facteur $r=3$. Ce facteur est la raison (ratio commune) de la suite. Le terme général de cette suite est alors: \[u_k=f(k)=3^{k-1}, \quad k\in \mathbb{N}^*\]
 \item Pour calculer la somme 
\[
1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots+n^3=\sum_{r=1}^n r^3
\]
on utilise la formule
\(
(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1
\). On arrive alors au résultat 
\[
\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2
\]
 \end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it was not my impression but I was right. May I ask you why you remove the `helvet`package?

Comment: @Dimitris I removed helvet because you are anyway overwriting the font with the lato package, so it seems unnecessary to load helvet first.

Comment: Great! Thanks again for your clarification!

Comment: @Dimitris Talking about package to remove: if your tex installation is reasonable up-to-date, you can also remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default since a couple of years

Comment: @Dimitris You're welcome!